# Zip Multiple Subdirectories With Path To Individual Zips

Tags: python, zip, winzip

I need help editing the following script which Zips the contents of a directory. My end goal is creating a script that will look at C:\Test (which will have multiple directories inside) and make a new zip file with the contents of each directory in C:\Test. The tricky part is that I need the path to be C:\ even though the directories true paths are C:\Test. Is this possible or am I dreaming ?

Thanks

```
import zipfile, os

def makeArchive(fileList, archive):

    try:
        a = zipfile.ZipFile(archive, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        for f in fileList:
            print "archiving file %s" % (f)
            a.write(f)
        a.close()
        return True
    except: return False

def dirEntries(dir_name, subdir, *args):

    fileList = []
    for file in os.listdir(dir_name):
        dirfile = os.path.join(dir_name, file)
        if os.path.isfile(dirfile):
            if not args:
                fileList.append(dirfile)
            else:
                if os.path.splitext(dirfile)[1][1:] in args:
                    fileList.append(dirfile)
        # recursively access file names in subdirectories
        elif os.path.isdir(dirfile) and subdir:
            print "Accessing directory:", dirfile
            fileList.extend(dirEntries(dirfile, subdir, *args))
    return fileList

if __name__ == '__main__':
    folder = r'C:\test'
    zipname = r'C:\test\test.zip'
    makeArchive(dirEntries(folder, True), zipname)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the path of the file inside the archive as follows:

```
a.write(PATH_ON_FILESYSTEM, 
        DESIRED_PATH_IN_ARCHIVE
)
```

Comment: I can't seem to change the path, but I'll try that later. More importanly I need the scipt to creat multiple ZIP files for each directory. Currently the script make one large ZIP with each directory inside.